# Perl join adds leading semicolon?

Tags: perl, join

We loop through a database and push each row to an array

```
while (($carriergw) = $sth->fetchrow_array) {
  if ($rows >= 1) {
    push(@gwlist, $carriergw);
  }
  else {
    push(@gwlist, -1);
  }
}
```

This yields the array `(0 10)` for example. When I try to join the elements
by adding a semicolon after every element:

```
join(';', @gwlist)
```

The join function adds a leading semi colon (i.e. `;10;0`). What we need is just `10;0`. How
to get the list without any leading or trailing separators?

Comment: Your `@gwlist` array does not contain what you think it contains. In such situations, the `Data::Dumper` module is helpful: `use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper); print Dumper(\@gwlist)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your array `@gwlist` has an empty string or `undef` for its first element. How do you declare it? I think you have written

```
my @gwlist = undef;
```

If you write

```
my @gwlist;

push @gwlist, 10;
push @gwlist, 0;

print join ';', @gwlist;
```

then you will get `10;0` for output. You need to investigate where that first element came from.

By the way, your `while` loop is better written as

```
while (my ($carriergw) = $sth->fetchrow_array) {
  push @gwlist, $rows > 0 ? $carriergw : -1;
}
```

but the test on `$rows` is almost certainly unnecessary. You don't say where its value comes from, but it looks like you want to push a single `-1` if no rows were retrieved from the table. If that is the case then the `while` loop will never be entered, so not even the `-1` will be added to the array.

Comment: Hello Borodin. Thank you for your response and edit. When I first started I was struggling with regex and string manipulation of gwlist. Then I found `join`. Long story short, gwlist was originally declared as my `@gwlist='';`. I also refactored the while loop to us iff as you shown above. To answer your question rows is `my $rows = $sth->rows;`. I am just trying to make sure I handle this correctly since it's mission critical. Please advise.

Comment: 'so not even the -1 will be added to the array'. I missed that part. I think this is the case even with your refactored code? I should first test if row=0 and push -1 else do....

Comment: @NickCameo: That depends entirely on what `$rows` is. You don't mention it and it would have been wrong for me to guess. If you think you have to mark the end of an empty array then think again.

Comment: Hello Borodin, thank you for the prompt! I did mention it in my first response. `my $rows = $sth->rows;`. What I ended up doing was getting rid of the iff (will use that else where sparingly ;), and tested for row count 0 before pushing within the while loop. Cheers!

Comment: I'm sorry Nick, I thought I had read that first comment and so skipped over it. There is no need to test the value of `$sth->rows`, as the loop will never be entered if there are no rows that match the SELECT. Your loop should contain just `push @gwlist, $carriergw`, and if you really need a -1 in the array if there are no matches (and I can't imagine why you should) then you can just write `@gwlist = (-1) if @gwlist == 0` after the loop, which puts -1 into the array if it is empty.

Answer (score 2):

There probably is an empty element, an `undef` or just whitespace as the first (`gwlist[0]`) element of `@gwlist`. To get around it, you may shift the first element off, or use an array slice:

```
shift @gwlist;
join ';', @gwlist;
```

Or:

```
join ';', @gwlist[1..$#gwlist]
```

Comment: As I commented on perreal's answer, that first element probably shouldn't be there, and I think it's unwise to write code to remove it or ignore it. Depending on where it comes from, it is possible that it isn't *always* there.

Answer (score 2):

```
my @l = (undef, 0, 10);
print join(";", @l), "\n";
```

*Gives:*

```
;0;10
```

If you use warnings it also says:

```
Use of uninitialized value $l[0] in join or string at test.pl line 5
```

You can prevent this by filtering:

```
print join(";",  grep { defined $_ } @l), "\n";
```

Comment: That first element may also be an empty string, or perhaps just whitespace. I suggest that it would be best to investigate why it is being added, and fix it. Adding more code to fix the results of preceding faulty code isn't a nice way to go.

Comment: This looks like a db query, I highly doubt there is an empty string in an integer field. But you're totally right about verification. If OP uses warnings and not getting a warning then it may be an empty string.

Comment: SQLite would oblige if you tried to do that. But I imagine that the element has been added by a faulty declaration (it wouldn't be the first time I had seen `my @gwlist = ('')` used to declare an empty array) or by some code preceding the database read loop.

Comment: I *think* (although the OP hasn't confirmed) that the error cam from `my @gwlist = undef`. By the way, why are you using the very nasty identifier `l` which means nothing, and could easily be the digit `1`.